# Finding a Kernel Matrix on $ \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $ X = \mathbb{R}^n$ with inner product $⟨x, y⟩ = y^TQx$ for some symmetric positive definite matrix $Q$. I have a few questions about this setup and generally about the kernels.

1- A kernel is the property of linear maps we define on a vector space (right?). So is it correct to say "the associated kernel to $\mathbb{R}^n$"?

2- How do I determine the Kernel and verify $span\{k_1, . . . , k_n\} = X$ and $⟨k_j, k_i⟩ = K_{ij}$. We need to find a map $\phi$ that $K(x,y)= ⟨\phi(x), \phi(y)⟩$ So is $K(x,y)= ⟨x, Qy⟩$ , a kernel?

3- A Kernel $K$ is positive semi definite matrix. if  $v^TKv = 0$, can we deduce that $Kv = 0$ for $v \in\mathbb{R}^n$?

4- And if $span\{k_1, . . . , k_n\} = X$ can we assume that can be equipped with an inner product for sure?

Comment: The kernel of a linear map is the preimage of $\{0\}$. Typically finding a kernel involves solving a system of linear equations. Inner products are bilinear however, not linear so they don't have a kernel. Any vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ can have an inner product defined over them.

Comment: @domath There are two common definitions of "kernel" in this context. The first question seems to be about the [kernel in the sense of a nullspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)), and the rest of your question seems to be about [positive definite kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel).

Comment: To answer your first question: the phrase "the associated kernel to $\Bbb R^n$" does not make sense (for either definition, though it's closer to making sense for the first definition).

Comment: To your second question: the map $K(x,y) = \langle x, Qy \rangle$ is indeed a kernel. It is sometimes referred to as a "linear kernel" because we can find an associated map $\phi$ (typically referred to as a "feature map") that is linear.

Comment: To your third question: it is not true that a kernel is a positive semidefinite matrix. However, for a positive semidefinite matrix $Q$, it is true that $x^TQx = 0 \implies Qx = 0$.

Comment: Your fourth question is uninterpretable in its current form. Presumably, $k_1,\dots,k_n$ refers to the columns of your "kernel" $K$, which is a matrix somehow. It's not clear what you mean by "can be equipped with an inner product".

Comment: @CyclotomicField For future reference, there is another "kernel" at play here (which has had a bit of a resurgence in the machine learning community over the past 10-20 years)